# Change Validation Rules for ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my register view, I have:

```
<div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
```

If I use a password like `foobar100` the validation fails however the error message doesn't provide a proper reason why it failed. I.e. `The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.` It will only work if I do something like `foob@r100`.

Is there a way to reduce the strictness of the validation rules? Or at least change the validation error message?

**Update**

The data validation attributes on the object I am checking are:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

which say nothing about requiring an @ symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the validation strictness. E.g. not have the need for alphanumeric characters. You need to alter the `MembershipProvider` properties. This can be done via the `web.config` file as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters.aspx.

```
   <membership>
          <providers>
              <clear/>
              <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                enablePasswordReset="true"
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
      </membership>
```

You can then better control the level of strictness via Danny Tuppeny's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the data validation attributes on the Password property of the whatever object you're checking.

Comment: See my update, the validation fails for `foobar100` even though it meets the StringLength attribute requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can add messages to the DataAnnotations attributes on properties, like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"/tags/[^\ ]+", ErrorMessage = "Url must start with /tags/ and must not contain spaces")]
public string Url { get; set; }
```

These will be used by the `ValidationMessageFor` helper to output the correct message.